# Why does my jquery onclick handler not work with dynamically added content?

Tags: jquery, html

http://jsfiddle.net/7sgT3/

HTML:

```
<button type="button" id="btn1">Button 1</button>
<div id="result">

</div>
<div id="message">

</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#btn1").click(function() {
        $("#result").html('<button type="button" id="btn2">Button 2</button>');
    });
    $("#btn2").click(function() {
        $("#message").text('Hello World !');
    });
```

When click to button 1, it will show button 2. 
But click button 2, not show message.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7sgT3/

Answer (score 2):

You can only attach an event if the button exists. Try this:

```
$("#btn1").click(function() {
    $("#result").html('<button type="button" id="btn2">Button 2</button>');
    $("#btn2").click(function() {
        $("#message").text('Hello World !');
    });
});
```

Comment: That's not entirely true.

Comment: Yea, you can bind it with live. Or the not depricated version of live.

Comment: Or with `$.on()`, which is not deprecated.

Comment: Never needed to use it since live became depricated. In most of the cases it's bad practice.

Comment: `$.on()` is the correct way to do event delegation. As long as it's not putting an event handler on `body`, it is not equivalent to `$.live()`.

Answer (score 2):

Your button (`#btn2`) isn't present in the DOM when the page loads. Simply change it to this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#btn2', function(){
    $("#message").text('Hello World !');
});
```

[**`JSFiddle Demo`**](http://jsfiddle.net/W6Kgt/)

Comment: Nice ! Thanks for aswer. Can i using .live click ?

Comment: @Phongdatgl `.live()` is deprecated. jQuery suggests using `.on()` instead.

Comment: @Phongdatgl does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can delegate with `$.on()`:

```
$("#btn1").click(function() {
    $("#result").html('<button type="button" id="btn2">Button 2</button>');
});

$('#result').on('click', "#btn2", function() {
    $("#message").text('Hello World !');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7sgT3/1/

Comment: @Vennik's answer is acceptable, but personally I prefer this solution. Makes for cleaner code.

Answer (score 0):

because at the time that you used jquery to find btn2, it doesn't exist yet.  You need to register the click handler right after you have created the actual button.